# Trouble finding a suitable Search API

Tags: search-engine, google-search-api, bing-api, search-engine-api

I need web search and site search results in feed format for a project and it's harder than ever now. Google has [killed](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html) it's Web Search API and now they charge $5 per 1000 queries with their [new API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html). If it were per million I could afford it.

Bing API is another option but their TOS prohibit placing non-Microsoft ads alongside the results and acceptance into their Ad program is not guaranteed.

If you're involved in a project that uses search, please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have the same problem with a project that will use search engines to find data. The only way that I think is possible is to make a bot that make queries on google.com and parse the html results. @Chad What did you do?